# Is it possible to get the style of a tab file I open in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I'm trying to duplicate a map made in mapinfo pro with QGIS in order to create shp files for geoserver.
When opening the tabs in QGIS they get some random style instead the one defined in mapinfo pro.
Is it possible to auto create the same styles or do I need to manually redefine them

Answer (score 1):

Try Nathan's Mapinfo to QGIS style converter: http://woostuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/new-tool-mapinfo-to-qgis-style-converter/

Comment: I've installed Python 3.3 on my machine and when trying to run the script I get error :
File "mapinfoToQgis.py", line 4
    <!DOCTYPE html>
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: not sure, but pretty certain the script is python 2.7

Comment: 2.7 also not working :(
thx for trying.

Comment: are you sure you downloaded the script correctly. Doctype html would indicate that you save some webpage instead. save this: https://raw.github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator/master/mapinfoToQgis.py

Comment: That was right , than I redownload it using the "Download" button and got error from the TAB saying :
!table not recognized.