# Mapinfo to QGIS. How to separate features in the same TAB

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, tab

Why does QGIS open my Mapinfo TAB and automatically merge all features (that causes  the colors of each features to change to a random unique color for all)?

How can I separate those features in QGIS and keep them in the same TAB like they are in Mapinfo... so I can apply the right color to each of them?

Comment: As in respect the styles that MapInfo has set for each feature?

Comment: The features are not merged just coloured the same, go to the styles tab and set any styling you require. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/basic_vector_styling.html

Comment: The styling in MapInfo is per feature whereas in QGIS it is per layer. You can, however, style objects based on attribute information which may provide what you are looking for.

Comment: This question may help, it's about copying styling from mapinfo into QGIS. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43257/is-it-possible-to-get-the-style-of-a-tab-file-i-open-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Oh... the styles... I might have missed something here :) I will have a look at that. Thanks guys, that will help me a lot!

Comment: Since version 3.20 QGIS can read the symbology settings of polylines. Line features are displayed as in MapInfo. But the symbology of point and polygon layers are still not recognizad in QGIS. It is planned to be implemented in the 3.22 version (October 2021)